# Twitter bootstrap problems with content being hidden under footer and navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

beginner here. Currently using twitter bootstrap, along with my own html, css, and js. However, on some pages when content is a lot more than the actual page it seems to be hidden underneath the footer or the top navbar. I included a part of the site, and I have tried messing around with the margins or padding but it does become a problem when I reduce the size of the window as I am using the responsive mode.

Any help would be great thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Weblio</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">       
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>       
    <!--navbar here-->
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner navbar-fixed-top">
            <a class="brand" href="/" ><i class="icon-phone-sign icon-2x"></i></a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <!--<li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li> --> 
                <li>  
                    <form id="login" class="form-inline" method="post">
                        <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me   
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse signIn">Log in</button>
                    </form>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>    

     <!--content-->
    <div class="centerContent">
        <div id="header">   
            <h1>This is the FAQ page.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="faqheader">
            <h3>Question 1?</h3>
            Nunc iaculis leo nec orci iaculis interdum eu at magna. Sed condimentum condimentum rutrum. Proin felis libero, volutpat vel congue ultricies, ultricies id risus. Phasellus scelerisque mi eu velit imperdiet vel interdum arcu rhoncus. Nunc sagittis sagittis lectus et faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas placerat feugiat neque eu interdum. Etiam massa ligula, faucibus at molestie sit amet, lobortis non nunc. Sed volutpat aliquam lorem sit amet tincidunt.   
        </div>
        <div class="faqheader">
            <h3>Question 2?</h3>
            Nunc iaculis leo nec orci iaculis interdum eu at magna. Sed condimentum condimentum rutrum. Proin felis libero, volutpat vel congue ultricies, ultricies id risus. Phasellus scelerisque mi eu velit imperdiet vel interdum arcu rhoncus. Nunc sagittis sagittis lectus et faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas placerat feugiat neque eu interdum. Etiam massa ligula, faucibus at molestie sit amet, lobortis non nunc. Sed volutpat aliquam lorem sit amet tincidunt.    
        </div>
        <div class="faqheader">
            <h3>Question 3?</h3>
            Nunc iaculis leo nec orci iaculis interdum eu at magna. Sed condimentum condimentum rutrum. Proin felis libero, volutpat vel congue ultricies, ultricies id risus. Phasellus scelerisque mi eu velit imperdiet vel interdum arcu rhoncus. Nunc sagittis sagittis lectus et faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas placerat feugiat neque eu interdum. Etiam massa ligula, faucibus at molestie sit amet, lobortis non nunc. Sed volutpat aliquam lorem sit amet tincidunt.    
        </div>
        <div class="faqheader">
            <h3>Question 4?</h3>
            Nunc iaculis leo nec orci iaculis interdum eu at magna. Sed condimentum condimentum rutrum. Proin felis libero, volutpat vel congue ultricies, ultricies id risus. Phasellus scelerisque mi eu velit imperdiet vel interdum arcu rhoncus. Nunc sagittis sagittis lectus et faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas placerat feugiat neque eu interdum. Etiam massa ligula, faucibus at molestie sit amet, lobortis non nunc. Sed volutpat aliquam lorem sit amet tincidunt.    
        </div>
        <div class="faqheader">
            <h3>Question 5?</h3>
            Nunc iaculis leo nec orci iaculis interdum eu at magna. Sed condimentum condimentum rutrum. Proin felis libero, volutpat vel congue ultricies, ultricies id risus. Phasellus scelerisque mi eu velit imperdiet vel interdum arcu rhoncus. Nunc sagittis sagittis lectus et faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas placerat feugiat neque eu interdum. Etiam massa ligula, faucibus at molestie sit amet, lobortis non nunc. Sed volutpat aliquam lorem sit amet tincidunt.    
        </div>
        <div class="faqheader">
            <h3>Question 6?</h3>
            Nunc iaculis leo nec orci iaculis interdum eu at magna. Sed condimentum condimentum rutrum. Proin felis libero, volutpat vel congue ultricies, ultricies id risus. Phasellus scelerisque mi eu velit imperdiet vel interdum arcu rhoncus. Nunc sagittis sagittis lectus et faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas placerat feugiat neque eu interdum. Etiam massa ligula, faucibus at molestie sit amet, lobortis non nunc. Sed volutpat aliquam lorem sit amet tincidunt.    
        </div>
        <div class="faqheader">
            <h3>Question 7?</h3>
            Nunc iaculis leo nec orci iaculis interdum eu at magna. Sed condimentum condimentum rutrum. Proin felis libero, volutpat vel congue ultricies, ultricies id risus. Phasellus scelerisque mi eu velit imperdiet vel interdum arcu rhoncus. Nunc sagittis sagittis lectus et faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas placerat feugiat neque eu interdum. Etiam massa ligula, faucibus at molestie sit amet, lobortis non nunc. Sed volutpat aliquam lorem sit amet tincidunt.    
        </div>
        <div class="faqheader">
            <h3>Question 8?</h3>
            Nunc iaculis leo nec orci iaculis interdum eu at magna. Sed condimentum condimentum rutrum. Proin felis libero, volutpat vel congue ultricies, ultricies id risus. Phasellus scelerisque mi eu velit imperdiet vel interdum arcu rhoncus. Nunc sagittis sagittis lectus et faucibus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas placerat feugiat neque eu interdum. Etiam massa ligula, faucibus at molestie sit amet, lobortis non nunc. Sed volutpat aliquam lorem sit amet tincidunt.    
        </div>

    </div>

    <!--footer-->
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div id="footer"> Weblio &#169; 2013  | <a href="/about.html">About</a> |<a href="/faq.html">FAQ</a> | <a href="/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="/terms.html">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="/contactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
            <div id="socialFooter"> 
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" title="Like us on Facebook."><i class="icon-facebook-sign icon-3x"></i></a>
                <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank" title="Follow us on twitter."><i class="icon-twitter-sign icon-3x"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS.

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
clear:  both;
background-color: #e1e1e1;
padding: 20px;
 }

#footer {

font-size: 16px;

 }

#socialFooter {
float:  right;
 }
```

And using the twitter bootstrap css file and responsive css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [this is what your page looks like](http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/z5hmK/show/) then the behaviour you describe with the content sliding under the top navbar and the footer is an intentional feature of Bootstrap. If it's not what you want, then remove the `navbar-fixed-top` and `navbar-fixed-bottom` from those two divs.

By default the fixed behaviour isn't activated on viewports < 980px

Good luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/z5hmK/

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I didn't think it would hide the content but I understand the feature more.

Comment: I actually noticed it works but that problem remains of my footer moving up if there is not enough content to keep it pushed down and that is why I originally used the fixed class. Do I need to just add padding to solve that or is there another more efficient way?

Comment: @Leo it sounds like what you want is the sticky footer http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html  I can see why you thought that the fixed bottom class might do this, but they aren't quite the same thing. Hope this helps

Comment: that's great, now you're off!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
.container-if-fixed-header
 {
    margin-top:50px;
}
.container-if-fixed-footer
{
    margin-bottom:55px;
}
```

Apply above classes into your container, as

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
       <!--HEADER content here-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container container-if-fixed-header container-if-fixed-footer">
       <!--BODY content here-->
       <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
           <div class="container">
              <!--FOOTER content here--> <p>&copy; Company</p>
           </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```